# Dozer: Removing fields from base class

Tags: java, marshalling, unmarshalling, dozer

I have a lot of classes that extends a single base class. While doing dozer mapping what I want to do is have one mapping for the base class and refer that mapping while mapping any of the sub classes.

For example:

```
<mapping map-id="BaseClassToMap" map-null="false">
    <class-a>com.example.BaseClass</class-a>
    <class-b>com.example.CustomMap</class-b>
    <field-exclude>
        <a>valueA</a>
        <b>this</b>
    </field-exclude>
</mapping

<mapping map-id="SubClassToMap" map-null="false" extends="BaseClassToMap">
    <class-a>com.example.SubClass</class-a>
    <class-b>com.example.CustomMap</class-b>
    <field-exclude>
        <a>valueB</a>
        <b>this</b>
    </field-exclude>
</mapping>
```

so when I do something like

```
CustomMap customMap = mapper.map(baseClassObj, CustomMap.class, "SubClassToMap");
```

the resulting customMap has valueA excluded.

Comment: So, what is your problem here ? Is there any Error in doing the above Mapping or else you are looking for some sort of mapping as you done above.